# Matlab dimensions must agree error. What's going on?

Tags: matlab

I'm getting:

```
Error using == ... Matrix dimensions must agree. 
Error (line 9) - if move2 == 'south'
```

What's going on?

```
disp('Welcome Dr. Doofenshmirtz.');

move1 = input('You are now in room number 1. Would you like to move West or North?: ','s');




if move1 == 'north'
    disp('You are now in room 4.');
    move2 = input('would you like to move south or east?: ','s');

    if move2 == 'south'
        disp('you are back in room 1.');
    elseif move 2 == 'east'
        disp('you are now in room 5');
    else 
        disp('There is no door there. You are still in room 4.');

    end
end
```

Comment: Use [`strcmp()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although both the parameters that you are comparing are string of characters but in MATLAB you can not simply compare two set of character strings with different array size. Array dimensions must agree for that matter.
In your case as suggested by Daniel you can use either of the below:

strcmp() - Compares the strings taking into account their cases.

strcmpi()- Compares ignoring cases.

These commands returns a Logical value (either 0 or 1)-if match is found value will be 1 (true) otherwise 0 (False).

I have re-phrased the codes for you:

```
  disp('Welcome Dr. Doofenshmirtz.');
  move1 = input('You are now in room number 1. Would you like to move West or North?: ','s');
  p = strcmpi('north',move1);
  if p==1
     disp('You are now in room 4.');
     move2 = input('would you like to move south or east?: ','s');

     z=strcmpi('South',move2);
     if z==1
        disp('you are back in room 1.');
     else z=strcmpi('East',move2);
         if z==1
            disp('you are now in room 5');
         else disp('There is no door there. You are still in room 4.');
         end
     end
  end
```

You haven't provided condition for West from 1st input so I have skipped that one.

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 3):

'south' is a char array with 5 chars, `==` is an element-wise comparison. `'south'=='north'` returns `[01011]` because it compares each char.

Take a look at `strcmpi` or `strcmp`